# Word boundary detection doesn't seem to work for me in Python re

Tags: python, regex

I tried using:

```
>>> wbpat='\btest\b'
>>> re.findall(wbpat, 'a test tested in testing')
```

The result that expected to get was ['test'] but somehow I am getting an empty list. What could be the problem...

Comment: see also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30164054/raw-string-and-regular-expression-in-python

Answer (score 4):

`\b` is an escape code for a backspace (length 1 string).  Use `r'\btest\b'`.  The leading `r` indicates to the Python interpreter that it should interpret each character in the string as a literal single character (a "raw" string) and ignore escape sequences.

Example:

```
>>> len('\btest\b')    # <backspace>test<backspace>
6
>>> len(r'\btest\b')   # <backslash>btest<backslash>b
8
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\btest\b','a test tested in testing')
['test']
```

It's a good habit to use a raw string for regular expressions in Python.